# toLocalDateString function to return a date in format DD MMM YYYY is throwing an "is not a function" error in browser console

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a date which is in the string format of `2021-03-31T00:00:00`. I want this date to be in the format DD MMM YYY so it appears like `31 Mar 2021`.

I have used the following code in the typescript file:

```
const formattedDate = i.SuspensionEndDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' });
```

When I run in the browser, I get this error in the console:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: date.toLocaleDateString is not a function
> TypeError: date.toLocaleDateString is not a function

I get a similar error when using the following code to extract only the DD element using getDate():

```
const formattedDate = i.SuspensionEndDate.getDate();
```

> jQuery.Deferred exception: date.getDate is not a
> function TypeError: date.getDate is not a function

I've not seen these errors before even though I have been able to do the same thing with JavaScript in the past. Though it's the first time doing it in a .ts TypeScript file.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `i.SuspensionEndDate` to `Date` object before format.

```
const formattedDate = new Date(i.SuspensionEndDate).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' });
```

Here's working example:

```js
const exDate = "2021-03-31T00:00:00";

const date = new Date(exDate).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric' });

console.log(date);
```